# need help to understand answer

Tags: conic-sections

Write the equation of a parabola with a vertex at $(-5, 2)$ and a directrix $y = -1$.

i got $(y-2)= \frac{1}{4} (x+5)^2$

Correct   answer is
$(y-2) = \frac{1}{12}  (x+5)^2$

Comment: i would like to understand this so i dont fail the test on wensday

Comment: Maybe look up a derivation of the formula for the equation of a parabola in terms of its vertex and directrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a parabola is the locus of a point which is equidistant from a line (the directrix) and a point not on the directrix (the focus).

since the vertex is at a distance $3$ from the directrix, the $y$-coordinate of the focus must be $2+3$, i.e. $5$. the $x$-coordinate in this case is the same as for the vertex, $-5$.
Y
take a point $(x,y)$ on the parabola:

distance from directrix = $y-(-1) = y + 1$

distance from focus = $\sqrt{(x-(-5))^2+(y-5)^2}$

squaring these distances and setting the results equal gives:

$$
(y+1)^2 = (x+5)^2+(y-5)^2
$$
rewriting as
$$
(y+1)^2-(y-5)^2 = (x+5)^2+
$$
using the difference-of-two-squares factorization gives
$$
6(2y-4)=(x+5)^2
$$
which is easily reduced to the answer you require